# Constants namespace in local scope

Tags: c++

I often read about using a namespace constants for... well constants.
I tried to take over this habit, but I am a bit unsure about local scopes.

Is it okay to make a namespace constants in the cpp-File for local use?
When the constants are for a class, is it better to put them in private?

I often have constants strings which I only need in local scope:

```
namespace Constants
{
 const std::string cMsg = "Msg";
}
```

If have found many different practises, so I am unsure how to implement it.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I am unsure what it is you're actually asking. It does seem like you don't completely understand namespaces. Also, keeping all the string constants together can be beneficial if you are ever planning to translate your program.

Comment: When I have more h-Files with namespace Constants, then isn't there a risk of having constants with the same name when they are all included in the main? In most cases I only need them in local scope, for a class or a few functions. So my question, should I put the namespace in the cpp-File or is/are there different solutions/practises?

Comment: if you consider that everything should be placed inside a namespace, then the namespace isnt that relevant for whether you use constants defined in the source file. Afaik the term "namespace constants" does not exist